# SEO and a large amount of Forms/Javascript links for a search functionality

Tags: javascript, forms, seo

I'm currently reworking an internal search engine for a website that lists products. This search engine has 3 categories with multi-choice options, and the client wants his search to be "SEO-Friendly", therefore he wants search options to be in the URL by name because he believes that will make it SEO-Friendly.

Problem is, the URLs produced by the search can break 2000 characters, and the possibilities might as well be endless with how many options there are, I think there are more than 10000 combinations. And the search URL is currently sent to the browser through Javascript, not through a Form element with a submit button. I doubt search engines would even crawl the latter properly.

I do not believe that it is possible to make this search SEO-friendly. And I believe that the amount of duplicated content might result in a penalty. Outside of barring SEs from crawling the search links at all, what would be a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

From users point of view, I think the >2000 characters URL is your biggest problem, because, for example, [IE will only handle URLs up to 2083 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427). I believe this should be a deal breaker.

A while ago we (Google) wrote up a post on faceted navigation, which I think applies to your case: [Faceted navigation best (and 5 of the worst) practices](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/02/faceted-navigation-best-and-5-of-worst.html). The worst practices section mentions:

> **Worst practice #2: Using directories or file paths rather than parameters to list values that don’t change page content.**
>   *Worst practice:*
>      `example.com/c123/s789/product?swedish-fish`
>   (where /c123/ is a category, /s789/ is a sessionID that doesn’t change page content)
>
> *Good practice:*
>   `example.com/gummy-candy/product?item=swedish-fish&sid=789`
>   (the directory, /gummy-candy/, changes the page content in a meaningful way)
>
> *Best practice:*
>   `example.com/product?item=swedish-fish&category=gummy-candy&sid=789`
>   (URL parameters allow more flexibility for search engines to determine how to crawl efficiently)
>
> It’s difficult for automated programs, like search engine crawlers, to differentiate useful values (e.g., “gummy-candy”) from the useless ones (e.g., “sessionID”) when values are placed directly in the path. On the other hand, URL parameters provide flexibility for search engines to quickly test and determine when a given value doesn’t require the crawler access all variations.

JavaScript in general shouldn't be a problem for at least the bigger search engines, Google and admittedly Bing are both rendering the HTML, fetching external resources as necessary, just like a standard browser would. Here you have to keep an eye on resources disallowed by `robots.txt` directives. If search engines can't crawl critical resources for rendering, they might completely misunderstand the page.